# Run bash script with python - TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to write python file, which wxtrac tar file in python.

As I understand, `subprocess` is the appropriate tool for this mission.

I write the following code:

```
from subprocess import call


def tarfile(path):
   call(["tar"], path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tarfile("/root/tryit/output.tar")
```

When output is the tar file, which located in `/root/tryit/`.

When I run it, i get the following message:

```
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Can I use tar command with this tool?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should specify the command as a list. Beside that, main option (`x`) is missing.

```
def tarfile(path):
    call(["tar", "xvf", path])
```

BTW, Python has a [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html):

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open("/root/tryit/output.tar") as tar:
    tar.extractall()  # OR tar.extractall("/path/to/extract")
```